# How to check if a body is a sphere

Tags: c#, siemens, nxopen

I want to check what is the body type of the body I'm working with in a `BodyCollection` (If the body is `Sphere`).

How do I write that?

This is what I tried:

```
public void ChamferAll()
{
    int subtype = 1;
    string offset1 = "5", offset2 = "0", angle = "5";
    BodyCollection bodyCollection = theSession.Parts.Work.Bodies;
    List<Tag> edgeTags = new List<Tag>();
    foreach (Body body in bodyCollection)
    {
        
        if (body.GetType() == NXOpen.Features.Sphere)
            continue;
        else
        {
            Edge[] edges = body.GetEdges();
            foreach (Edge edge in edges)
            {
                edgeTags.Add(edge.Tag);
                theUFSession.Modl.CreateChamfer(subtype, offset1, offset2, angle, edgeTags.ToArray(), out Tag chamferTag);
            }

            edgeTags.Clear();
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`body.GetType()` returns the type of the body, e.g., sheet or solid. "Sphere" is not a body type.

What you can do instead is use `body.GetFeatures()` to get a list of the features associated with that body. Then select the first returned feature, and try casting it to `NXOpen.Features.Sphere`. If that works, the body you've got is a sphere. If the cast doesn't work, you have something other than a sphere.